# Printing matrix form in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I need a code for the following example given below. Here is the code which I tried and there should not be a newline (\n) at the end of the matrix:

```
r=int(input())
c=int(input())
count=1

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print(count)
        count=count+1
print()
```

**Input**

```
r=2

c=2
```

**Output**

```
 1 2

 3 4
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried in order to solve this? Also, are we talking just pure python or numpy?

Comment: @roganjosh Pure python

Comment: You want `np.arange(1,x+1).reshape((row,col))` where `x=row+column`

Comment: here is my code                     r=int(input())
c=int(input())
count=1
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print(count)
        count=count+1

Comment: Oh, We seem to have posted at the same time. I didn't see that

Comment: @Shashi Please paste your code in the question which you have tried.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. (Rereading it, that does sound a little harsh.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 sounds good :)

Comment: @RohitPotter I edited my question, please check it once. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function
m = int(input("Enter the row:"))
n = int(input("Enter the column:"))

num = 1
# iterate over the rows and print each row
for i in range(m):
    row = " ".join(map(str, range(i*n + 1, (i+1)*n + 1)))
    print(row)
```

Since an edit was made to the question:

```
m = int(input("Enter the row:"))
n = int(input("Enter the column:"))

count = 1
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print(count, end=" ")
        count += 1
    print()
```

Comment: There should n't be a newline(\n) at the end of matrix @Deepak Saini

Answer (score 0):

```
r = int(input())
c = int(input())
count = 1
for i in range(r):
      for j in range(c): 
            print(count,end=' ')
            count=count+1
      print()
```

Comment: Hope this does the work for you

Answer (score 0):

Going off your code:

```
def print_matrix(rows, columns):
    # maximum width of column, including spaces
    pad_len = len(str(rows * columns)) + 1

    for y in range(rows):
        for x in range(columns):
            print("{n:>{pad}}".format(
                n=y * columns + x + 1,
                pad=pad_len
            ), end='')
        print()

print_matrix(18, 37)
```

I've replaced the counter with something calculated from `x` and `y`; hopefully you can see how that's done. Also, it uses padding so that the columns always line up, even for really big numbers.